# Does one ever use apostrophes when writing plurals?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe

I am writing an essay on blood types and the Japanese culture, and I am not quite sure if my use of apostrophes is correct.

I've read through this article, *[Apostrophes](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp)*, but I can't seem to find this situation.

Here is what I have written; is this the correct format?

> Type A's are cool, calm, and conscientious. Type B’s are practical, relaxed, and the most unconventional.

Comment: Check out Rule 6.

Comment: Since Rule 6 shows both usages, does it mean it's okay to use either one?

Comment: It's fine. Your choice of adjectives is a little odd, though.

Comment: This, like all punctuation, is a matter of style, and as such, you should be guided by your manual of style.  I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which recommends that which will avoid ambiguity.  You don't want "As" to mean the plural of "A" because that looks like the word *as* at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @Ricky, which adjectives are youo referring to?

Comment: @deadrat, thank you very much for your explanation about manuals of style. I'll have to do more research, as I am not familiar with manuals of style.

Comment: If you're writing for someone other than yourself, that organization will likely have a manual of style that they require that you use.  Ask your editor or instructor.  If you're writing for yourself, then choose a manual geared toward the field you're writing about.

Comment: What I tend to do is to avoid the need to pluralize individual letters by rewording slightly.  Rather than "students with A's", eg, I'd write "students with A grades".  It's not so big a deal in a simple reference like that, but if the text gets "busy" the plural letters get confusing, no matter how you handle them.